# How to reproduce the beautiful LIB style box as in the tcolorbox document using mdframed package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, mdframed

I tried to reproduce the beautiful LIB type box as in tcolorbox document using mdframed package. But I failed, I don't know how to produce the clip effects using mdframed package. The rotated rectangle is somehow 
bigger than the background box...

My code :

```latex
% !Tex program    = xelatex
% !Tex encoding   = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
%-------------------------------
%    Lib mdbox
%-------------------------------      
\newmdenv[     skipabove    =7pt,
                skipbelow    =7pt,
                leftmargin   =0cm,
                rightmargin =0cm,
                topline         =true,
                bottomline   =true,
                leftline         =true,
                rightline       =true,
                linewidth     =.4pt,
                innertopmargin=4pt,
                innerbottommargin=4pt,
                innerleftmargin=4mm,
                innerrightmargin=4mm,
                roundcorner=1pt,
                linecolor=green!50!black,
                backgroundcolor=green!10!white,
                fontcolor =green!25!black,
                singleextra={%
                \path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$)
                   node[
                                                         fill=green!75!blue!50!white,
                                                         text=white,
                                                         font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,
                                                         rectangle,
                                                         rounded corners=1pt,
                                                         rotate=90
                                                         ] 
                                       {REM};
                         \path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x1,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$)
                   node[
                                                         fill=green!75!blue!50!white,
                                                         text=white,
                                                         font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,
                                                         rectangle,
                                                         rounded corners=1pt,
                                                         rotate=90,
                                                         ] 
                                       {REM};              
                                   },
                ]{mylibmd}%
%-------------------------------
%    Lib tcbbox
%-------------------------------      
\newtcolorbox{mylibtcb}{
                                    enhanced,
                                    before skip=7pt,
                                    after skip =7pt,
                                    left skip=0pt,
                                    right skip=0pt,
                                    boxrule=0.4pt,
                                    top=0pt,
                                    bottom=0pt,
                                    left=4mm,
                                    right=4mm,
                                   arc=1pt,
                                   boxsep=4pt,
                                  %before upper={\vphantom{dlg}},
                                  colframe=green!50!black,
                                  coltext=green!25!black,
                                  colback=green!10!white,
                                 overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
                                 \fill[green!75!blue!50!white] 
                                 (frame.south west)
                                   rectangle      node[text=white,
                                                         font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,
                                                         %rectangle,
                                                         rotate=90
                                                         ] 
                                       {REM}
                            ([xshift=4mm]frame.north west);
                            \fill[green!75!blue!50!white] 
                                ([xshift=-4mm]frame.south east)
                                   rectangle      node[text=white,
                                                         font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,
                                                         %rectangle,
                                                         rotate=90
                                                         ] 
                                       {REM}
                            (frame.north east);
                            \end{tcbclipinterior};
                                     }
                              }
%-----------------------------
%  document
%----------------------------
\begin{document}
%\section{library}
  The following is  \textbf{a mdbox}created by using \textbf{the mdframed package}:
   \begin{mylibmd}
    good good study day day up day day up
   \end{mylibmd}

   The following is a \textbf{a tcbbox} created by using \textbf{the tcolorbox package}:

   \begin{mylibtcb}
    good good study day day up day day up
   \end{mylibtcb}
\end{document}
% END
```

The diffence is shown in the picture[image]

Comment: Can you give a minimal example that can be compiled?

Comment: Why do you want to switch to mdframed?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer   I am interested in the differences between these two packages, and want to know the strong points and weak points by comparison. Yeah, I know the tcolorbox is much more powerful overall.

Comment: @AndréC  Thanks for the advice.  I have re-edited the code.

Comment: Sorry if you want to procrastinate it is your decision but I won't spent my time on such a question.